# Capitalizing only the first letters without changing any numbers or punctuation

Tags: matlab

I would like to modify a string that will have make the first letter capitalized and all other letters lower cased, and anything else will be unchanged.

I tried this:

```
    function new_string=switchCase(str1)
%str1 represents the given string containing word or phrase
str1Lower=lower(str1);
spaces=str1Lower==' ';
caps1=[true spaces];
%we want the first letter and the letters after space to be capital.
strNew1=str1Lower;
strNew1(caps1)=strNew1(caps1)-32;
end
```

This function works nicely if there is nothing other than a letter after space. If we have anything else for example:

```
     str1='WOW ! my ~Code~ Works !!'
```

Then it gives 
     new_string =
    'Wow  My ^code~ Works !'
However, it has to give (according to the requirement),

```
    new_string =
    'Wow!  My ~code~ Works !'
```

I found a code which has similarity with this problem. However, that is ambiguous. Here I can ask question if I don't understand.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question +1.

I think the following should fulfil your requirements. I've written it as an example sub-routine and broken down each step so it is obvious what I'm doing. It should be straightforward to condense it into a function from here.

Note, there is probably also a clever way to do this with a single regular expression, but I'm not very good with regular expressions :-) I doubt a regular expression based solution will run much faster than what I've provided (but am happy to be proven wrong).

```
%# Your example string
Str1 ='WOW ! my ~Code~ Works !!';

%# Convert case to lower
Str1 = lower(Str1);

%# Convert to ascii
Str1 = double(Str1);

%# Find an index of all locations after spaces
I1 = logical([0, (Str1(1:end-1) == 32)]);

%# Eliminate locations that don't contain lower-case characters
I1 = logical(I1 .* ((Str1 >= 97) & (Str1 <= 122)));

%# Check manually if the first location contains a lower-case character
if Str1(1) >= 97 && Str1(1) <= 122; I1(1) = true; end;

%# Adjust all appropriate characters in ascii form
Str1(I1) = Str1(I1) - 32;

%# Convert result back to a string
Str1 = char(Str1);
```

Comment: Your code works! However, I am quite a new user of MATLAB. Logical() was new for me. It is a logical array that what I found. okay. But, I did not understand this. What is (.*) doing here actually?
"I1 = logical(I1 .* ((Str1 >= 97) & (Str1 <= 122)))" 
Then isn't Str1(1) just the very first character of the string which is 'W' here? Apparently, it is not. It checked all the first characters after a space. But how it worked?
Thanks!

Comment: @user3226108 1) `logical` simply converts a vector of 1's and 0's that are in "double" format (64 bits) to binary format (1 bit). 2) `.*` is element-wise vector multiplication. Basically, I wanted to turn all the 1's in I1 that didn't index lower case characters to 0's. So I multiplied each element by another logical vector that takes value 1 if an element is a lower case character and a 0 otherwise (note 97 to 122 are the ascii numbers representing lower characters). 3) `Str1(1)` is the first character of the string. It is "W", although in ascii format, ie 87. Cheers!

Comment: @user3226108 Also, if you are new to Matlab, and in particular, new to working with matrices, then what I've done will probably seem a bit dense. Just try pulling every single expression out of every line one a time and seeing what they do by examining the variables in the workspace. One other thing, I notice you are fairly new to StackOverflow. If you think I've answered the question, then feel free to click the tick mark next to my answer. If not, then let me know why and I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: @user3226108 Gah! Quick correction to my previous comment. I said `Str(1)` was "W". Actually, at that point in my code we have already applied the `lower` function, so `Str(1)` would actually be "w", or in ascii format, 119.

Comment: Why are we checking only the first character of the string? Why not the each character that's just after the space? I am sorry....maybe a dumb question. I don't know!

Comment: @user3226108 This line: `I1 = logical([0, (Str1(1:end-1) == 32)]);` constructs an index of all locations after a space *excepting the first character*, since by construction there will be no space before the first character. Nonetheless, we may need to capitalize the first character if it is not a symbol. Therefore the first character needs to be treated as a special case, which is what we do with this line: `if Str1(1) >= 97 && Str1(1) <= 122; I1(1) = true; end;`. Note, without that line, the first character would still be lower case, even though everything else would be correct.